# How do I control the position of a carat in a TableView Column header?

Tags: javafx, tableview, tableheader

I notice that there is a carat available in a date column of a TableView which allows the user to toggle the view between descending and ascending order. However the carat it not initially visible until the user clicks somewhere in the table header row, and then it appears at whatever position the cursor is in in the table column row.

In SceneBuilder I have searched for a control called Carat but none exist, so there is no way to modify the characteristics of a carat object. Also in the SceneBuilder > Inspector > Properties I searched for any attribute for the column header that might control the characteristics of the carat, but none appear to exist. I also similarly looked in SceneBuilder > Inspector  > Layout and > Code to see if I could find a way of setting the carat position or creating an event handler that might do the job, but I was not successful.

The code listed renders the date column for me in the overridden initialize method:

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
 ...
txnDateCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->        cellData.getValue().localtxnDateProperty());
...
}
```

I would like and ascending and descending carat to be displayed, right justified, in the TableView date column.

Comment: Please provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A screen shot is even more helpful.

Comment: if you mean the sorting icon, then _then it appears at whatever position the cursor is in in the table column row_ is not true: it always appears at the trailing edge of the a column header if the column is sorted. Sorting state of a column is cycled on clicks, starts with unsorted -> ascending -> descending. So what exactly is your problem? If there are several problems, please ask several questions, otherwise it's hard to answer :)

Comment: @Sai Yes a screenshot would be a good way to indicate the problem but I have not found any instructions in the formatting guidelines about how to do this. I am investigating this and will post a screenshot asap as this would amply show the issue I am having.